# Function to convert array to string and capitalize it don't work

Tags: c++, function, vector, type-conversion

```
void convertString(string text, vector<char> arrName) { // converts string and capitalize the input
    copy(text.begin(), text.end(), back_inserter(arrName));
    transform(arrName.begin(), arrName.end(), arrName.begin(), toupper);
};
```

If i put these 2 manually, it works, but not if i call them in a function with the string name eand the vector that will receive the values.
This is the context:

```
//asking for plaintext
string plainText, key, keyStream, cipherText;
vector<char> textArr(plainText.begin(), plainText.end());
//plaintext
cout << "Type the text you wanna cipher, followed by the key: ";
cin >> plainText >> key;
vector <char>txtArr;
convertString(plainText, txtArr); // function being called (doesn't assign nothing to the txtArr vector)
```

Comment: Your function should accept `arrName` by reference in order to modify it (change `vector<char> arrName` parameter to `vector<char> & arrName`).

Comment: It worked, thank you. 
Why does it needs the &? What is this "accept by reference"? Can you point me to a direction? I wanna understand more about why this happened.

Comment: It's rather a basic concept in c++. I think you will benefit from getting a good c++ book. It's very hard (if not impossible) to learn c++ properly just by searching around.

Comment: I'm actually going through Principles and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup, but i'm still on the beginning, on babysteps.